Anchor build not working
When I try to run anchor build in my terminal, this is the result I am getting in the terminal.
I have uninstalled and installed rust but I am still getting the same output.


What version of Solana and anchor have you installed? Are you using WSL or Windows powershell?

I use anchor version 0.30.0 and Solana version 1.18.15
I have tried both wsl and windows powershell. I am getting the same result.

could you try downgrading to 1.18.2 and anchor 0.29.0 and see if there are any differences

I am still getting the same error.

Please use text instead of screenshots so other people can find your question.

This looks like a bug in the typenum crate that you're using. You're using Windows, which doesn't allow for / in the paths, but the code is trying to include a file directly at https://github.com/paholg/typenum/blob/b237efbb1da9646435274f63d7290cb7651b031f/src/lib.rs#L72
You might need to fix that code to use a join instead, just like https://github.com/paholg/typenum/blob/b237efbb1da9646435274f63d7290cb7651b031f/build/op.rs#L20

How do I do that?
